# javascript get dom element children from all depths

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an HTML code like this:

```
<div id="test">
    <div id="test1">
        <div id="test2">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to take all children of the element "test", so I made a recursive function:

```
function getObjectChildren(elem) {
    var elemChildren = elem.childNodes;
    var result = [];
    result.push.apply(elemChildren);
    for (k = 0; k < elemChildren.length; k++) {
        if (elemChildren[k].childNodes.length > 0) {
            result.push.apply(getObjectChildren(elemChildren[k]));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var a = getObjectChildren(document.getElementById("test");
```

The thing is, this recursive function enters an infinite loop. Does anyone know why this happens and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Beware of the global `k` variable.

Comment: Check the first argument of [```apply```](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Function/apply): ```result.push.apply(result, getObjectChildren(elemChildren[k]));```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed my problem:

```
function getObjectChildren(elem) {
    var elemChildren = elem.childNodes;
    var result = [];
    for (var k = 0; k < elemChildren.length; k++) {
        result.push(elemChildren[k]);
        if (elemChildren[k].childNodes.length > 0) {
            var tmp = getObjectChildren(elemChildren[k]);
            for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
                result.push(tmp[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```